# Short proof for triangle inequality

Tags: real-analysis

I don't understand this proof for triangle inequality from my textbook:

Prove:

$|a+b|\leq |a|+|b|$

Solution:

$-|a|\leq a\leq |a|$

$-|b|\leq b\leq |b|$

$-(|a|+|b|)\leq a+b\leq |a|+|b|$

$\Rightarrow |a+b|\leq |a|+|b|$

I understand that they added $-|a|\leq a\leq |a|$ and $-|b|\leq b\leq |b|$ but I can't see how they got the last row.

Comment: The book used the fact that if $ -r<x<r $ then $|x|<r$.

Answer (score 1):

So from $-(|a|+|b|)\leq a+b \leq (|a|+|b|)$ -- you are comfortable with this step?

If I take the absolute value if this inequality, we only need consider the right hand side
$$|a+b| \leq \big |(|a|+|b|)\big |$$
***Why only consider the RHS? -- QUICK EXAMPLE***
$$-1000\leq 10\leq 1000$$
if we take the absolute value of both sides, and consider the left hand inequality as true, then we get that $1000\leq 10$ which is clearly nonsensical.

***Hope this ignoring the LHS is now justified enough!***

So now only considering the RHS $\Rightarrow | a+b| \leq |(|a|+|b|) | $

But $|a|+|b|\geq 0$ so taking the absolute value no longer has any effect, and we get that 
$$|a+b|\leq|a|+|b|$$
as required.

Answer (score 1):

For any $ c $ we have $|c|=\max (-c,c).$

From the first inequality $-(|a|+|b|)\leq a+b$ of the second-last line, we have $$  \bullet \quad  |a|+|b|\geq -(a+b).$$  The second inequality of the second-last line is equivalent to $$ \bullet \quad  |a|+|b|\geq (a+b).$$ Combining these we have $$|a|+|b|\geq \max (-(a+b),(a+b))=|a+b|.$$